# Is testing web app on android native browser is enough?

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, webview, android-webview

Is testing a mobile web application only with the native browser is enough? Is there any chances that the mobile web application might behave different with other browsers available for mobile like Chrome, Firefox etc. I mean Mobile Chrome and Mobile Firefox, how they are different in terms of rendering the web page than native browser , they follow different logic like the desktop versions or take support of native components of android like webviews?

Answer (score 1):

Testing with the native browser is definitely not enough. You should test on as many browsers as possible among those you can reasonably expect your users to use. Every browser is different: they support JavaScript features differently and they support CSS differently. Even different versions of the same browser might provide significantly different user experiences for the same web app. (We've found this, for instance, with the Android Chrome browser and the Chrome Beta browser.)

Answer (score 0):

For most common APIs, you should not have a problem. However, when your web app gets more complex, it is usually a good idea to test on as many browsers as possible.

Mozilla has extensive documentation on interesting APIs', and if you use any of these, it is a good idea to check if other browsers support them.
The information can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

At the end of the day, the imperative is on you as the developer to ensure that your app supports your target audience as well as possible.